# What is a DART Iframe?

Tags: html, web, iframe

This [Google page](http://www.google.com/support/richmedia/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117427) refers to a "DART Iframe".  Does DART stand for something?  I seem to be missing some crucial piece of cultural understanding.

Comment: DART, in this context, seems to stand for ["Dynamic Advertising, Reporting, and Targeting"](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/DART) (look for "DoubleClick" on that page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page provides a link to the answer: http://www.applecider.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=917

"After a quick google search for "Dartiframe.html", this looks to be a filename associated with the company "doubleclick", who is involved with online advertising."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubleclick/

Also at this site: http://www.webmasterworld.com/google_adsense/3773640.htm

I've done a little research and dartiframe seems to be a file you would install if you were using doubleclick and wanted media ads to break out of their iframe.

Comment: Yeah, the link I posted says something similar, and I understand what the file is, I want to know why it is called a DART Iframe, rather than just an iframe.  @Quack Quixote seems to have found a reasonable expansion.

Comment: @Chas.Owens Because DoubleClick was formally named DART. Including the company name in the file would help distinguish it in network traffic, and it still having that name after the rebrand would merely be a technology legacy which they haven't gotten around to fix yet.